# if $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence such that $a_n \in [c,b]$ and $a_n \rightarrow a$ then $a \in [c,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

> if $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence such that $a_n  \in [c,b]$ and $a_n \rightarrow a$ then $a \in [c,b]$

I just wanted to make sure I was writing a correct proof and communicating my ideas correctly.

**Proof**

Suppose $a \notin [c,b]$. Given that $a_n \rightarrow a$ this means: $$\forall \  \epsilon >0,\ \exists \ N\in \mathbb{N} \ s.t.\ \forall \ n \geq N \ |a_n - a| < \epsilon$$

$$\Rightarrow \ \exists \ a_n \ s.t. \ a_n \notin [c,b]$$

Not sure if I have to give this explanation after, but since $a_n$ converges to $a$ it means eventually that $a_n$ and $a$ are going to be so close or equal that   $a_n$ will not be able to be in $[c,b]$

Comment: Your proof is a bit hand-wavy.  I think a better proof would be a proof by contradiction:  Suppose that $a_n \to a$, $a_n \in [b,c]$ for all $n$, and yet $a > c$, for example.  What goes wrong in that case?

Comment: I thought I did a proof by contradiction?.....

Comment: Your last $\Rightarrow$ doesn't really follow (yet).  Take @JavaMan's hint, and measure the distance from $a$ to $c$.  Cut it in half...

Comment: @Randall I'm not sure it makes much of a difference, but I stated the interval as $[c,b]$ whereas JavaMan stated it $[b,c]$. If I take the interval as $[b,c]$ and assume $a>c$ then I would get the same sort of conclusion I had, as in $a_n \notin [b,c]$......but if I took it as $[c,b]$ I don't see how a contradiction would arise....

Comment: You won't get a contradiction until you choose a very special $\epsilon$.

Comment: @Randall I tried letting $\epsilon = \frac{|a-c|}{2}$ but I'm not seeing the contradiction....

Comment: You're there.  There is an $N$ so that when $n > N$ we have the distance from $a_n$ to $a$ is less than $\epsilon$.  But those $a_n$'s are to the left of $c$, a contradiction.  (I'm back to using your original notation $[c,b]$ for the interval.)

Comment: @Randall....I am not seeing how the $a_n$'s are to the left of $c$? My distance from $a_n$ to $a$ is less than $\epsilon = \frac{|a-c|}{2}$ but where does it show that some of these $a_n$'s are to the left of $c$? Also I am confused about assuming $a>c$ since this is what we want to show somewhat....

Comment: It is an immediate consequence of order property of limits. If $a_n\leq b_n$ and both the sequences are convergent then $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n\leq \lim_{n\to\infty} b_n$.